# Not Found 404 Error when running Java Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty-9

I have this *Java* web app running on a *Jetty* v9 container using a *Mongo* database. Using *Maven*, I run

```
mvn clean install
```

In order to build the project. It generates a jar file for Jetty, which I can successfully launch from the console:

```
java -jar myProject.jar
```

Then, I load the following address on a browser and the app loads correctly

[image]

making first a redirection to

[image]

Now I try to do the same in *Eclipse Luna*. I right-click on project *jetty-wrapper* which contains *myProject.jar* in the target directory, select *Debug Configurations* and create a *Java Application*, as shown in the image below:

[image]

When I press *Debug* this app is apparently successfully launched, as the console shows:

[image]

Then, I load the following address on a browser

[image]

As before, the app makes a redirection, **but this time the html page is not found**:

[image]

A few days ago this was working fine and I don't recall having made any change to the project at all!!

**What might be the problem?**

Comment: In the future, using *version control* will help you know for sure if you've made any changes.

Comment: To be more precise, according to my *version control* it's clear that I haven't made any changes to the *code*. As for other changes (e.g., project configuration, installation/uninstallation of Eclipse plugins etc.), I don't recall having made any either.